# Why should I "refer to the OECD Core Competencies" in a job application, and how?

Tags: applications

I found a job ad which fits my skills and I want to apply.

There are the typical application paragraphs, so the structure is like:

> **Ideal Candidate Profile**
>
> *Academic Background*
>   .....
>
> *Professional Background*
>   .....
>
> *Tools*
>   .....
>
> *Languages*
>
> - good knowledge of one of the two official languages of the Organisation (English and French) and a good knowledge of, or willingness to learn, the other.
>
>   Please refer to the OECD Core Competencies and the level 2 indicators.

and then contract information follows.

Now I don't understand this request:

> Please refer to the OECD Core Competencies and the level 2 indicators.

Then a link to their [Competency Framework booklet](http://www.oecd.org/careers/Competency%20framework_booklet.pdf) follows.

I don't know what I have to do? Is this only concerning the languages? Is there a specific task I have to do, like evaluating myself in the different fields (analytics, personal) in my application with the level/grades given in the document?

What do I have to write / add in my cover letter or in my cv?

Comment: The link is taking me to a "Page not found" page.

Answer (score 5):

They are telling you that the job you are applying for is classified as Grade B4-B6 or C5-C6, and that you will be expected to have and demonstrate what they describe as Level 2 (and, of course, Level 1) competencies.

Those mostly involve the ability to think for yourself, solve problems, and deal with some unexpected conditions, while recognizing when you need to seek advice. You won't be tested/screened for these abilities, but you will need to demonstrate at interview and in your cv/covering letter how you meet the required competencies.